# java.io.IOException: null InputStream when changing higher SDK version in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am very new to android and java development.

I am trying to devlop an app and integrate one SDK from [Emarsys](https://help.emarsys.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004899497-Android-integration-Mobile-Engage-Android-SDK).. This SDK requires the app to use higher sdk version.

But after changing the SDK version to the higher version (33), I have an error and the app is always being terminated immediately..

```
 DropBoxUtil             pid-9840  [AppErrors] null InputStream [CONTEXT service_id=254 ]
                                                                                                    java.io.IOException: null InputStream
                                                                                                        at boqn.c(:com.google.android.gms@230413037@23.04.13 (150400-505809224):23)
```

Here is my gradle.bundle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.ionic.starter"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')

  //for emersys
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    //Emarsys
  implementation 'com.emarsys:emarsys-sdk:3.4.0'
  implementation 'com.emarsys:emarsys-firebase:+'

}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

gradle in project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.ionic.starter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="io.ionic.starter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>


<!--      Emersys-->
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.emarsys.mobileengage.notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.emarsys.mobileengage.small_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/default_small_notification_icon" />


      <service
        android:name="com.emarsys.service.EmarsysFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </service>

<!--      <provider-->
<!--        android:name="com.emarsys.provider.SharedHardwareIdentificationContentProvider"-->
<!--        android:authorities="${applicationId}"-->
<!--        android:enabled="true"-->
<!--        android:exported="true"-->
<!--        android:grantUriPermissions="true" />-->


    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

I am not sure what causing it, because I haven't even started to integrate the service from SDK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by taking the latest version of emarsys and emarsys firebase

```
implementation 'com.emarsys:emarsys-sdk:+' 
implementation 'com.emarsys:emarsys-firebase:+'
```

Answer (score 1):

In `build.gradle (project)`, update Google Service dependency to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```